# Viewing a post from the Android profile feed and then navigating back always causes scroll to top

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, android-app

When viewing your profile feed from the Android app, every time you go into a post and then navigate back to the feed (either via Android's back button or the back button in the UI), it always takes you right to the top of the profile feed, meaning you have to scroll again to where you were.

The Android app didn't used to do this. I like to review my posts and comments, and it is much easier via the Android app as it combines all the Stack Exchange sites into one history list. However, this bug now makes this impractical.

This is on Lollipop on a Samsung Galaxy S5.

Comment: Not repro'd on Nexus 5, Lollipop 5.1.1, SE app v1.0.68. Could you provide the app version too?

Comment: The app is version 1.0.68.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed in the next update (anything higher than 1.0.68) -- Sorry about the regression, we updated to a new version of the Android support library and it seems to have some weird bugs.